# Where do you store static data frontend or backend?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, web, frontend

Let's assume there is a form frontend, which has several dropdowns with data(objects, not just strings) that likely not changing in the future, but it has reasonably size, so it looks a little bit weird putting it into frontend.

Do you create tables for these data backend and fetch it from there even though the backend likely not using or changing it ever?

Could you give me some resources where I can find about these conventions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of this data it is more efficient to have this on frontend stored in some constants file, no problem whether they are  objects or strings. For example,create class DropdownOption and store array of these  objects.

If you decide to keep it in database and provide data via REST API count on the performance - every request will reach your endpoint first, create transaction, get data from db, close transaction, map objects to dtos and only after that return to your frontend. More data more time.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I would be interested in the response who downvoted your answer aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Further from Ilia Ilin's answer, an additional thing to consider is if this data set is referenced anywhere, how you'd like the data to behave once a value is updated or removed.

If you load the data on the front end, then any modification will not apply to previously stored data.

If you store the data in a relational DB, fetch it in front end, any modification will cascade to all previous data references.